# Excel: If column A matches, add column B value horizontally in column C

Tags: excel

Is it possible to match values from column A and if they match, add all matching values from column B to column C horizontally?

I've attached an example of the excel as image.

[image]

Comment: What Excel do you have?

Comment: I have Excel 2007